# Load image array passed as props in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in console valid path is show. but when i give this in to Image Source like this source={this.props.data[5].var} also try this source={{uri: this.props.data[5].var }} but is show nothing. if any one know this problem let me know

myfirst page code is:

export default class HomePage extends Component {

```
Details = [
    {
        id: 1,
      "type": "Cariyaka",
      image: require("../assets/cariyaka.png"),
      var: "../assets/panyaka.png"
    },
    {
        id:2,
      "type": "ettyaka",
      image: require("../assets/ettyaka.png"),
      var: "../assets/panyaka.png"
    },
    {
        id:3,
      "type": "panyaka",
      image: require("../assets/panyaka.png"),
      var: "../assets/panyaka.png"
    },
    {
        id:4,
      "type": "pan10",
      image: require("../assets/pan10.png"),
      var: "../assets/panyaka.png"
    },
    {
        id:5,
        "type": "ett10",
        image: require("../assets/ett10.png"),
        var: "../assets/panyaka.png"
      },
      {
          id:5,
        "type": "chari10",
        image: require("../assets/chari10.png"),
        var: "../assets/panyaka.png"
      }
```

];

frontpage=()=>{

```
Actions.second(this.Details);
```

}

and second page code is:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.data[5].var);
  
  

 return (
    
    <LinearGradient  colors={['#95c2a1', '#c7bbbb', '#738299']}
    style={{
    
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1, alignItems:'center'
    }}
    start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
    end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}>
    <ScrollView>
 
    <Image
            style={styles.icon}
  
              
            source={this.props.data[5].var} 
          />
```

Comment: You need a width and height for your images, they won't display otherwise.

Comment: i have tried. Nothing is happening.

Comment: ```console.log(this.props.data[5].var);``` is writing some output? If it is can you share with me?  And how you're passing this array to the component?

Comment: thanks for your response. this issue is solved. that issue is in k source var